# Titanium click event in MenuIcons

Tags: javascript, click, titanium, appcelerator, dom-events

I am standing on **MainMenuScreen**, from there I added a module name **MenuIcons** But I don't know why the click events in **MenuIcons** is not working at all. However, all views, images and other content is showing perfectly without any warning or error.

Here is the scenario of code:

**MainMenuScreen.js**

```
function MainMenuScreen(userinfojson) {
    var main_window = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundImage : '/assets/inventoryBackground.png'
    });
    var MainScreen = [];
    var MenuIcons = require('ui/common/menus/MenuIcons');
    MainScreen.menuIcons  = new MenuIcons(active_screen);
    main_window.add(MainScreen.menuIcons);

    var StatusScreen = require('ui/common/MenuScreen/StatusScreen');
    MainScreen.statusScreen = StatusScreen(userinfojson);
    main_window.add(MainScreen.statusScreen);

    return main_window;    
}
module.exports = MainMenuScreen;
```

**MenuIcons.js**

```
function MenuIcons(active_menu) {
    var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
        top : "12%",
        height : "10%"
    });
    var iconstatus_imageview = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        left : '0%',
        top : '0%',
        image : '/assets/iconStatus.png',
        height : '100%',
        width : '13.8%'

    });
    iconstatus_imageview.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert("Clicked");
    });

    view.add(iconstatus_imageview);
    return view;
}
module.exports = MenuIcons;
```

So, click event of this "**iconstatus_imageview**" `imageview` is not working
Please help...:(

Comment: Which OS, IOS or Android?  Also, what is active_menu parameter suppose to do?  You aren't using it in the function.

Comment: It is for 2.2 Android. active_menu parameter is just for some calculation which is not pasted here.

Comment: are you sure Titanium / JS likes underscores for variable names?

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot this I would add colors to the views/windows involved and see if one is drawn over the other.  My initial guess without seeing the StatusScreen code is that it is over the top of the MenuIcons, but it is transparent and you can't see it.

I would probably comment out this line and see if the menu event fires:

```
main_window.add(MainScreen.statusScreen);
```

This code works, so the problem isn't visible in the code you pasted.  So whatever code you edited out should be looked at.

app.js

```
var main_window = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    //backgroundImage : '/assets/inventoryBackground.png'
    backgroundColor: 'white'
});
var MainScreen = [];
var MenuIcons = require('MenuIcons');
//MainScreen.menuIcons = new MenuIcons(active_screen);
MainScreen.menuIcons = new MenuIcons();
main_window.add(MainScreen.menuIcons);

// var StatusScreen = require('ui/common/MenuScreen/StatusScreen');
// MainScreen.statusScreen = StatusScreen(userinfojson);
// main_window.add(MainScreen.statusScreen);

//return main_window;
main_window.open();
```

MenuIcons.js

```
function MenuIcons(active_menu) {
    var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
        top : "12%",
        height : "10%"
    });
    var iconstatus_imageview = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        left : '0%',
        top : '0%',
        image : 'medical.png',
        height : '100%',
        width : '13.8%'

    });
    iconstatus_imageview.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        alert('clicked');
    });

    view.add(iconstatus_imageview);
    return view;
}
module.exports = MenuIcons;
```